# How do you set the window icon in a WPF OpenFileDialog?

Tags: .net, wpf, icons, openfiledialog

Putting custom icons on windows and menus is really simple in WPF, but somehow changing the icon on an OpenFileDialog fto be something other than the application icon is eluding me.

I realize OpenFileDialog() is not creating a WPF control, since it's coming from the Microsoft.Win32 namespace, but there must be a way to set the icon used.

Comment: It might help that in winforms the icon used by this form is inherited by the parent window. For example, if the parent window form has `ShowIcon = false` the OpenFileDialog will not show an icon.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you get the handle of the dialog, you can do it like this:

```
IntPtr icon=win32.LoadIcon(win32.GetModuleHandle(null), "icon resource name");
win32.SetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_HICON, icon);
```

Getting the handle is trickier, you have to override `WndProc` and watch for messages after creating the dialog.